# Is it possible to have different styles in one element in Jaspersoft?

Tags: jasper-reports

Let's say I need to print the full name of a person. What I originally did was to separate the first name and last name into two elements and placed them side by side since they needed different styling (this is just an example):

**Lastname**, *Firstname*

However, I found out after that I can't actually make their width dynamic because the developers made an effort not to allow it. So now I'm wondering if I can present the name with two different styles inside one element. Is this possible? How would I accomplish that? I hope you can help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently you can. All you need to do is setup the markup attribute on the text field.

[image]

Refer here for more details: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/